# Wxpython Application Fails On Some XP Installations

Tags: python, debugging, windows-xp, wxpython

I am the developer or a simple software program written in Python/wxpython and packaged with py2exe. I've had reports from some users that the program doesn't run. All users who report this are running windows XP - but with my 2 XP test machines, I can't replicate the problem.

The weird thing - and what's making this so hard to debug - is that no error message is generated. Double-click on the exe, there's a short hourglass, then nothing happens. No process left running, no error message, no error log.

The error reporting appears to work fine. On my machine, if I remove, say, the wxpython DLL, then when I run it I get a messagebox saying an error occurred, and an error log written that reports the error, as coded. So if this were a dependency/packaging issue, i would expect some error report.

I can't find a difference between my XP test machine and that of the users who can't run the program. The machine has up to date. I have tried disabling anti-virus with no change in behaviour.

I'm hoping either:

- Someone has had a similar issue and can suggest a fix
- Could suggest at least some avenue to pursue. Right now I'm not sure how best to try and resolve this problem other than starting from scratch with a bare-bones python program and building it up from there. But being unable to replicate the problem leads makes it tricky to try and 'brute force' the issue.

Comment: what version of python and wxpython?

Comment: python 2.66 and wxpython and wxpython 2.8.11.0

Answer (score 1):

Try running Dependency Walker on the user's PC and see what it comes back with: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Also, if you're using bundle option 1 in py2exe, try switching to bundle option 3. I've had some screwy issues when I've used 1 before.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Re. bundle, I already have that set to 3. 

I asked the customer to provde the results from dependency walker. The following 3 DLLs show as errors "at least one delay-load module was not found": EFSADU.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL, WER.DLL.

I also ran the program myself (windows 7, the software runs). It reports that IESHIMS.DLL and GPSVC.DLL are missing.

Comment: Doing some google searching, it seems wer.dll and ieshims.dll are red-herrings. However this EFSADU.DLL may be a lead. Firstly it seems this isn't included in XP home (but is in XP pro) - this may explain why it's failing on some XP machines and not others?

Comment: Yeah. I don't think any of those are the issue. I suppose the UAC could be blocking the application somehow on the client's machine. If they're not already, have them try running it as an administrator. Otherwise, you'll probably want to ask on the py2exe or wxPython mailing lists.